# Como remover espaço em branco em um ponteiro de vetor?

Tags: c++

Possuo uma entrada de dados onde o usuário irá digitar uma certa quantidade de `char`, esta quantidade vem das primeiras entradas do tamanho dos vetores de acordo com a escolha do usuário...

**Como irá funcionar a entrada dos caracteres?**

- O usuário irá digitar em uma só linha todos os n caracteres pedidos, como por exemplo: `ABCDEFGHJILMN`
- Após a entrada do usuário cada char ficará em um `index` do `*ponteiro`

**O que está ocorrendo?**

> Não consigo controlar a entrada de dados para que o usuário não insira caracteres em branco, por exemplo:
>
> Caso ele insira `A B C D`, os espaços em branco serão armazenados em cada index do vetor

**O que estou tentando fazendo?**

> De acordo com a situação escrita acima, eu decidi ter a ideia de verificar quais `index` contém o espaço em branco, e após isto deletar (desalocar) da memória os mesmos e deixando o mesmo vetor com uma nova quantidade de dados e somente com os `char` **não brancos**...

**NOTA [IMPORTANTE]:**

> Não podem ser usadas funções predefinidas das linguagens para tratamento dos vetores (busca, pertinência, inserção, exclusão, ordenação, etc.).

**Como eu poderia fazer isto de um modo elegante e usando boas práticas?**

**Segue o meu algoritmo:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;


void cleanScreen() {
    system("CLS");
}

int validateDataEntry(istream& strm, int sze, char phrase[]){
    char inputTester;
    strm.get(inputTester);

    if(sze < 0) {
        cout << "============== PROGRAMA FINALIZADO! ==============" << endl;
        exit(0);
    } else {
        if(strm.fail() || sze < 0 || inputTester == '.') {

            while(true) {
                char inputTesterTwo;
                cleanScreen();

                cout << "VALOR DIGITADO INVALIDO.. UTILIZE APENAS NUMEROS POSITIVOS & INTEIROS!" << endl;
                cout << phrase << endl;
                strm.clear();
                strm.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                strm >> sze;
                strm.get(inputTesterTwo);

                if(!strm.fail() && sze > 0 && inputTesterTwo != '.') {
                    cleanScreen();
                    return sze;
                }

                if(sze < 0) {
                    cout << "============== PROGRAMA FINALIZADO! ==============" << endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        } else {
            return sze;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    char *vetorA, *vetorB, *vetorC;
    int sizeN = 0, sizeM = 0, sizeK = 0;

    // ENTRADA DO VETOR A
    cout << "DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DO [VETOR A]:" << endl;
    cin >> sizeN;

    sizeN = validateDataEntry(std::cin, sizeN, "DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DO [VETOR A]:");

    // ENTRADA DO VETOR B
    cout << "DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DO [VETOR B]:" << endl;
    cin >> sizeM;

    sizeM = validateDataEntry(std::cin, sizeM, "DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DO [VETOR B]:");

    // ENTRADA DOS CARACTERES DO VETOR A
    vetorA = new char[sizeN];

    cout << "DIGITE [" << sizeN << "]" << " CARACTERES PARA O [VETOR A].." << endl;
    cin.get(vetorA, sizeN + 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeN; i++) {
        if (isspace(vetorA[i])) {
            delete[] vetorA;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se é c++ acho que você está a complicar em várias vertentes, não só por não usar `std::string` como por estar a forçar a não utilização de funções de linguagem. O que quer fazer resume-se a `remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace);` assumindo que `str` é uma `std::string`.

Comment: de maneira geral não se usa falar " meu algoritmo", a não ser que você tenha criado um algoritmo novo em alguma área da ciência da computação...no caso o mais correto é falar "meu programa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Não consigo controlar a entrada de dados para que o usuário não insira caracteres em
>   branco, por exemplo:
>   Caso ele insira A B C D, os espaços em branco serão armazenados em cada index do vetor.

Se for só esse o problema, aqui vai um exemplo de entrada de dados ignorando espaços.
Estou usando vector porque simplesmente não faz sentido usar ponteiros e new neste caso, mas é possível adaptar a resposta caso seja proibido usar vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// ---

static void perform_data_entry(vector<char>& chars, int n)
{
  char ch;

  cout << "* digite " << n << " caracteres diferentes de espaco\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < n;)
  {
    cin.get(ch);

    if (isspace(ch))
      continue;

    chars.push_back(ch);
    ++i;
  }

  cout << "* ok, digitacao concluida\n";
}

// ---

int main()
{
  int sizeA;
  vector<char> vetorA;

  cout << "* qual e' a quantidade de caracteres ? ";
  cin >> sizeA;

  perform_data_entry(vetorA, sizeA);

  cout << "*\n";
  cout << "* caracteres digitados:[";

  for (auto ch: vetorA)
    cout << ch;

  cout << "]\n";
  cout << "*\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Poderias fazer assim:

```
char c;
int i = 0;

while (1)
{
    while((c = getchar()) == ' ')
        continue;
    if(c == '\n' || i == n)
        break;
    buffer[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```

O `while` interno salta quaisquer espaços em branco inseridos pelo usuario.